# using split in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

in one of my database fields i have data as follows:

```
value1, value2, value3
```

my search parameter could be value1 or value2 or value3

what i want to do is use a linq query to get a list of entities where for e.g. value2 is in "value1, value2, value3"

also, values are seperated by space after the commma.

i tried to use the following linq query but got an error that stated Array operation not permitted.

```
List<Players> c = (from p in db.Players
                      where (p.Users == "Everyone" || p.Users.Split()[','].Trim().Contains(username))
                      orderby p.Category ascending
                      select p).ToList();
```

any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: doesn't work either, same error.

Comment: You should post the comment on the relevant answer so that the answerer gets a notification.. What is the error you are getting now, it can't be same error.

Answer (score 7):

You are not doing the `Split` properly, it should be like:

```
p.Users.Split(',').Contains(username)
```

If you want to `Trim` each split value then:

```
p.Users.Split(',').Select(r=> r.Trim).Contains(username)
```

If you are using LINQ to Entities, then you might end up with an exception that `string.Split` can't be translated in to SQL query. In that case you might have to iterate (`ToList`) your results first and then compare it against the split array.

Comment: This is no longer working in ASP.NETCore it will throw 

'An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments'

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all it is not a good practice to use a datamodel where you need string split match. Because it leads to inefficient systems and not to mention slow queries. But yet, if you really need a solution why not try this -.

There are four occasions where you will get a match,

1. A prefix match - starting with
2. Inner Match - contains with
3. Suffix Match - ends with
4. The only match - only one item and this is it

considering the scenario I am suggesting the solution below -

```
username is the value looking for say "1"
string prefixMatch = username + ",";
string suffixMatch = ", " + username;
string innerMatch = ", " + username + ",";

List<Players> c = (from p in db.Players
                  where (p.Users == "Everyone" || (p.StartsWith(prefixMatch) ||
                                                   p.Contains(innerMatch) || p.EndsWith(suffixMatch) || 
                                                   (!p.Contains(",") && p == username)))
                  orderby p.Category ascending
                  select p).ToList();
```

This query will support LINQ-TO-SQL Conversion

Comment: A possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511565/linq-select-using-split/23514199#23514199