# Regex in LINQ query

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a LINQ statement like this:

```
var query = from s in persons
            where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || s.Name.trim().contains(name)) &&
                  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || s.Email.contains(email)) &&
                  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) || s.Zip == zip)
            select s;
```

The name field is coming from the user who can type the name on the web page and then I need to search the persons table for that particular name. Unfortunately, the name First Name and Last name are in the same column in the database and the other issue is there are two spaces between first Name and Last Name so for e.g. if the name is Steve Ramsey. the name in the database is  this way:

```
Steve  Ramsey
```

Not all the names are stored this way, only few names are like this. I have the Regex to eliminate one extra space:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
CustName = regex.Replace(CustName, " ");
```

I am not sure how to put this regex in LINQ query

Comment: `regex.Replace(s.Name, " ").Contains(name)`

Comment: you can use split with space : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056557/using-split-in-linq-query

Comment: Instead of Regex you can split input `name` into first and last parts, concatenate them using one and two spaces and then search for either concatenations.

Comment: Which ORM do you use and which version?

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 4.x / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x / 7.x / 8.x? What database provider?